# how to check property of directive in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am a simple directive with isolated scope .I need to test that directive using jasmine and karma .I make this directive like that

```
  .directive('helloWorld',function(){

      return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
          data:'=',
          message:'@'

        },
        templateUrl:'home.html',
        link:function(s,e,a){            

        }    
   }      
 })
```

how to test it's isolated properties like **data and message** using jasmine
I test my controller like that

```
describe('http controller test', function() {

  var $rootScope,
    $scope,
    controller,
    $q,
    $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');

    inject(function($injector) {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $injector.get('$controller')('first', {
        $scope: $scope
      })       
    })
  })

  describe('Init value', function() {
    it('check name value', function() {
      expect($scope.name).toEqual('apple');
    })    
  })

  it('it should be true', function() {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy(); 
  })
 })
```

I used **templateUrl**  can I test my directive using templateUrl ? I don't know how to test directive and it's properties ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/dplJ6sf4kgiwJ5pXu4GE?p=preview

can we add karma-ng-html2js in my plunker to test directive

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor

any example in plunker

Comment: You should consider testing directive _behaviour_ instead of it's internal state.

Comment: so how i test directive behaviour  ?

Comment: Here is [one good tutorial](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-directives/), [here's another one](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/testing-directives.html), there are plenty of resources on internet too. Generally you want to imitate user actions, call `scope.$digest()` and check generated HTML for results.